# SAP HANA: Minimum value of several columns

Tags: sql, hana

I have some columns in SAP HANA Index Server:

```
ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3
---+-------+-------+------
 1 |     5 |     3 |    2
 2 |     7 |     9 |    8
 3 |     5 |     4 |    6
```

How can I get the minimum value per line?

Expected result:

```
ID | MIN   
---+-------
 1 |     2 
 2 |     7 
 3 |     4
```

So far I tried

```
SELECT ID, min(COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) FROM ...
```

But `min()` seems to support only two columns at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming none of the values are `NULL`, then use `LEAST()`:

```
select least(col_1, col_2, col3_3)
from . . .
```

Comment: sweet! Works very well. I ensured the `NULL` issue with a `COALESCE()`